# Getting command output from Invoke-Command

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to use Invoke-Command to run a command in PowerShell remotely on a number of machines, and capture their output from it, but I'm not getting any output from it.  I suspect it's from how I'm using Start-Process, but I'm not sure.

```
$RunCommand = {
    Start-Process "$env:ProgramFiles\Some Program\someprogram.exe" -ArgumentList "-SignatureUpdate"
}

$comp_list = @(Get-Content "c:\temp\comp_list.txt")
$cred = Get-Credential

$jobs = Invoke-Command -Credential $cred -Computer $comp_list -ScriptBlock $RunCommand -AsJob

Wait-Job $jobs
$r = Receive-Job $jobs
$r | % { $_ > c:\temp\$($_.PScomputerName).output }
```

Is there a better way to invoke a command using environment variables like that?

Comment: This may be a typo but shouldn't it be `Invoke-Command -ComputerName ` not just `-computer`

Comment: `-Computer` is an alias for `-ComputerName`, so either will work just fine.

Comment: ahh, should have figured. Have you tried using `$ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.NewScriptBlock()` to create the script block. I've used this with Invoke-Ssh command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found that `Start-Process` is probably not the best way to capture the output from a binary unless the binary itself passes on .NET objects.  What I did find that works better for this is the [call operator](http://ss64.com/ps/call.html):

```
$RunCommand = {
    $exe = "$env:ProgramFiles\Some Program\someprogram.exe"
    & $exe -SignatureUpdate
}
```

I was still not getting the output I was expecting.  More specifically, I was only getting the last line of output from the command instead of the entire thing.  Eventually it dawned on me that all the previous lines were being overwritten, and so I changed the last line to this:

```
$r | % { $_ >> c:\temp\$($_.PScomputerName).output }
```

Note: I changed `>` to `>>` for appending to the file.

Comment: To note, this has the drawback that rerunning the script results in it appending to the end of that same file instead of creating a new one.